# How to send tether token in ether wallet using web3

Tags: web3js, gas, react, typescript, tether

I am gonna send tether token from my wallet address to other wallet address using web3.

```
    const Web3 = require('web3');
    const web3 = new Web3('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/projectId');
    web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add('<private key>');
    var count = web3.eth.getTransactionCount("my wallet");
    var contractAbi = [];
    var tokenAddress = '';
    tokenInst.methods.transfer('where I send', 1).send({from: 'my wallet', gas: 100000});
    tokenInst.methods.balanceOf('my wallet').call().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

I have 75 USDT in my wallet.

If I run above code, I can check 75000000.

But I faced this error

'errors.js:28 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Returned error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value
at Object.ErrorResponse (errors.js:28)
at index.js:303
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (index.js:98)'

It would be appreciated if you could fix this. Thanks.

Comment: you probably need to have ether on that account to pay for the gas fee... https://etherscan.io/gastracker

Comment: Thanks Majd TL. I appreciate your help.... Could you please let me know how to define gas fee and what is gas limit and gas Price? So, how much ethers I need for gas fee on my account and what is minium value.

Comment: It depends on the time , version of web3, type of transaction (in good case it will cost u about 20$ in ether) :) can’t u just use metamask :/